# Sort data.table by grouping variable with condition

Tags: r, sorting, data.table, grouping

I have the following `data.table` (in fact my `data.table` is much bigger (more groups and more other variables)):

```
Data <- data.table(Group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3),
                   Var = 1:6)

> print(Data)
   Group Var
1:     a   1
2:     a   2
3:     a   3
4:     b   4
5:     b   5
6:     b   6
```

Now I want to sort the `data.table` based on the variable `Group` but only if `Group == "a"`.
My poor attempt was the following:

```
> Data[Group == "a", .SD[.N:1]]
   Group Var
1:     a   3
2:     a   2
3:     a   1
```

I know why this is wrong but I can not think of a solution that leads to my desired output:

```
   Group Var
1:     a   3
2:     a   2
3:     a   1
4:     b   4
5:     b   5
6:     b   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt would work with

```
library(data.table)
Data[Group == "a"] <- Data[Group == "a", .SD[.N:1]]
Data
#    Group Var
#1:     a   3
#2:     a   2
#3:     a   1
#4:     b   4
#5:     b   5
#6:     b   6
```

But the above just reverses the rows if you want to sort the rows in decreasing order based on `Var` you could do

```
Data[Group == "a"] <- Data[Group == "a", .SD[order(-Var)]]
```

---

If you have multiple columns you can do

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
Data[Group %in% cols] <- Data[Group %in% cols,.SD[order(-Var)],Group]
```

A better approach with `data.table` is to update by reference as suggested by @markus

```
Data[Group %in% cols, Var := .SD[order(-Var)]$Var]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if this will work if I have many groups and I want to order the rows for some of the groups.

Comment: @RonakShah Your second approach could also be written as `Data[Group == "a", Var := .SD[order(-Var)]$Var]` to modify `Var` by reference.

Comment: @markus yeah, I was trying that but couldn't get it right. Thanks, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without using the `.SD` notation:

```
> Data[Group == "a", Var := sort(Var, decreasing = TRUE)]
> Data

   Group Var
1:     a   3
2:     a   2
3:     a   1
4:     b   4
5:     b   5
6:     b   6
```

As you have a large data.table and more groups, you may wish to consider the use of the `.I` notation (see the [article](https://nathaneastwood.github.io/2019/09/14/selecting-the-max-value-from-each-group-a-case-study-data.table/) by [@nathaneastwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3759418/nathaneastwood)) as it does result in better performance in some situations. Here, `.I` will identify the row numbers of interest. Let us change the example so that we are interested in two groups:

```
Data <- data.table(Group = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 3), Var = 10:18)
```

Then:

```
> Data[Data[, .I[Group  %in% c("a", "c")]], Var := sort(Var, decreasing = TRUE), by = Group]

> Data
   Group Var
1:     a  12
2:     a  11
3:     a  10
4:     b  13
5:     b  14
6:     b  15
7:     c  18
8:     c  17
9:     c  16
```

For completeness the basic idea is contained in:

```
Data[Group %in% c("a", "c"), Var:= sort(Var, decreasing = TRUE), by = Group]
```